# How can I set a parameter for month in a batch file?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm writing a batch file which will be move files from one drive to another drive.

I receive files to the D: drive from other source daily. My E: drive has month wise folders like August 2013, September 2013 etc. I want to move the files for each month from D: to E: in their proper directory.

This is what I have so far:

```
@ECHO OFF 
:START 
XCOPY D:\AS\*.*/E/D E:\August 2013 (Here I want to set parameter for auto update of month, which should be pickup from System)
echo y | del %1*.* D:\AS\ 
:END
ECHO Quitting 
PAUSE
```

How can I set the month parameter in the batch file?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Where exactly are you getting stuck?  Perhaps post the code that you have completed so far, as it may help clarify.  Be aware, we're not a script-writing service.

Comment: @ECHO OFF
:START

XCOPY D:\AS\*.*/E/D  E:\August 2013   (Here i want to set parameter for auto update of month, which should be pickup from System)
echo y | del %1\*.* D:\AS\

ECHO Quitting
PAUSE

Comment: Can you please edit that into your question?  It will allow you to apply proper formatting. :)

Comment: I have edited your question but your question remains ambiguous: what is the current month? The time stamp of the file? The current date? Please edit.

Answer (score 0):

using `WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Month` will return a numerical value for the month (So if it's currently August, this will return `8`.) From there you could use variables and `Switch` to convert the number to the month name.